# smbclient: command not found

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to connect to a remote server with the `smbclient` command and pass some arguments to the script.

Here is my command:

```
smbclient //$SERVER -c 'cd $PATH;get $FILE /tmp/$FILE' $PASS -U$PSEUDO -W domain
```

When I launch this command without variables on the command line it works. But when I use it in the script it says:

```
./test1.sh: line 14: smbclient: command not found
```

Why is that?

```
Here is my complete script with for exemple arguments testSRV, testPATH and testFile :


\#! /bin/bash

SERVEUR=$1
PATH=$2
FILE=$3

echo $PATH #Return testPATH
echo $FILE #Return testFILE

\#COMPLETEPATH="cd $testPATH;get $testFILE /tmp/$testFILE"

\#echo $COMPLETEPATH //return

/usr/bin/smbclient //$SERVER -c 'cd $PATH;get $FILE' testpassword -U testuser -W testdomain
```

Comment: smbclient is installed on server or not?

Comment: Yes it is. Since the command works outside of the script.

Comment: you could do a `which smbclient` to give you the full path of the command in case the PATH is failing when you run the script.

Comment: My command is located in /usr/bin/smbclient

Comment: And the beggining of the script in standard #! /bin/bash

Comment: I'd put /usr/bin/smbclient where you've written smbclient in the script. If you still have the same issue you've definitely got something interesting happening and it'd be worth putting the whole script up in case an earlier line is causing it to break.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to post it correctly without make a new answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options: ensure /usr/bin is on your PATH (echo $PATH to see if this is the case) or edit the script to call smbclient with the full path (/usr/bin/smbclient)

Comment: Tried your two proposals but seems to be the same but one exceptions. When in my script I execute the command without any variable it works. Which wasn't the case yesterday without the complete command's path.

Answer (score 1):

It's good,

Thanks you all but I achieved to make my script works.

I tried to replace single quote with double quote and put the full command path